# Como realizar busquedas en JSON creado con MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, json, mariadb

Tengo que hacer muchas busquedas en una tabla SQL, por lo que se me ocurrio hacer 1 sola consulta seleccionado todo y guardarlo en un JSON de esta manera:

```
SELECT json_object('id', Id, 'nombre', nombre) FROM etiquetas
```

Lo que no se, es como buscar dentro de ese JSON (si es que se puede) y si estoy haciendo lo correcto o lo mas conveniente es hacer el bucle de consultas sql. Gracias!

Comment: Tu pregunta no se entiende del todo, pero me parece extraño que intentes ¿ *sustituir* ?  la base de datos por un JSON. ¿Por qué no buscas lo que necesites en cada caso directamente en la base de datos? ¿Por qué tienes que crear un JSON primero y luego hacer búsquedas en él? ¿Acaso las bases de datos no existen precisamente para guardar los datos de forma ordenada y óptima mediante índices para poder encontrar lo que necesitemos con un menor coste? Son sólo algunas preguntas para llamar a la reflexión.

Comment: @A.Cedano a como veo la consulta del OP, en donde tiene `json_object` me parece si tiene la info en una base de datos pero algunas columnas en formato JSON y por eso hace uso de la función mencionada antes; lo que convendría es que mejore su redacción pues es confusa, ya que dicha función `json_object` es para manejo de datos tipo JSON en mysql

Comment: @AlfredoPaz creo que la forma en que introduce la pregunta deja claro que quiere volcar un gran número de resultados en un JSON para luego buscar en el JSON y no en la BD, lo cual sería subestimar la capacidad de la BD, prefiriéndola a un JSON: *Tengo que hacer muchas busquedas en una tabla SQL, por lo que se me ocurrio hacer 1 sola consulta seleccionado todo y guardarlo en un JSON de esta manera...*  Eso es lo que yo quiero que él explique, **¿por qué sub-estima a la base de datos?**

Comment: tienes razón @A.Cedano disculpa, espero la aclaración

Comment: Buen dia gente, muchas gracias por sus respuestas!. No es sub-estimar la base de datos, es NO saber, por eso al final de mi pregunta pongo: **"si estoy haciendo lo correcto o lo mas conveniente es hacer el bucle de consultas sql"**. Por algun motivo pense que hacer un bucle de miles de consultas era sobrecargar el servidor y seria mas eficiente hacerlo de la manera detallada en mi enunciado.